# Variant of binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients, reference-request

I've recently come across a variant of the binomial polynomials, and I'm curious if anyone has seen these before.  If so, I'd love a reference, a name, etc.

First recall the following.  If z is a formal variable, then we can consider \binom{z}{k} as a polynomial in z by the standard formula: \binom{z}{k}= [z(z-1)...(z-k+1))]*[k!]<sup>-1</sup>.

Here's the variant I came across.  Let a and k integers, where a divides k, and we write k=ab.  Consider the polynomial

F<sub>(a,k)</sub>(z)=[z(z-a)(z-2a)...(z-k+a))][k(k-a)(k-2a)...(a)]<sup>-1</sup>.

Has anyone this before?  Or anything similar?

**Update:**  Jonah helpfully identifies a typo in the numerator of F<sub>(a,k)</sub>(z) which I've now corrected.

Comment: Well, from a polynomial perspective they're essentially the same.  Consider F<sub>(a,k)</sub>(az) and cancel the factors of a.  


Comment: Thanks for all of these great answers!  I had missed the change of coordinates and hadn't heard of multifactorials before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For simplicity, you probably want the last term in the numerator to be z-k+a, right? That way F<sub>(1,k)</sub>(z)=\binom{z}{k}. I'll pretend that's what you meant.)

I haven't come across such polynomials, but they're easily expressed in terms of [multifactorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Multifactorials). Namely,

F<sub>(a,k)</sub>(z)=z!<sup>(a)</sup>/[(z-k)!<sup>(a)</sup>k!<sup>(a)</sup>]

Note that this isn't an integer when a doesn't divide z. EDIT: (And, as Qiaochu points out, when a does divide z it's just regular ol' z-choose-k.)

Answer (score 3):

On the other hand, maybe what you want is a combinatorial interpretation.  There is a way to express a related function as a binomial determinant which can be combinatorially interpreted using Gessel-Viennot, as described [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?search_id=544586963&t=290277).

Comment: That's pretty awesome. I should probably get better at recognizing Gessel-Viennot applications when they pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Let B<sub>k</sub>(z) denote the usual binomial coefficient, suitably generalized to allow z to be a formal variable.  Assuming that you intend to have the same number of factors in the numerator and denominator in your definition of F<sub>(a,k)</sub>(z), then via the substitution z = aw,

F<sub>(a,ab)</sub>(z) = B<sub>b</sub>(w).

If 1/a is in your ring (still assuming that a divides k), then

F<sub>(a,k)</sub>(z) = B<sub>k/a</sub>(z/a).